# Why is my bearer token returning role claims as role instead of schema.microsoft.com identity/claims/role in the API?

Tags: c#, api, .net-core

I have this sign-in API call that calls a method to generate a token with the following claims

```cs
protected Claim[] GetUserClaims(User user)
{
    var res = new List
    {
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Sid, user.Id.ToString()),
    };

    if (user.UserRole == UserRole.Admin)
    {
        res.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin"));
    }

    if (user.UserType == UserType.User)
    {
        res.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "User"));
    }

    return res.ToArray();
}
```

When I look at the debugger it was showing as `schemes.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role` which I want but when I try to look at the identity claims again when I use the same bearer token I generated with the method it showed it as `role` instead of the aboved mention type.

How can I fix it so it is showing the schemes on the bearer token since I can't utilize my Authorization with roles

Comment: I think we'll need to see more code since this looks fine.

Comment: What is `ClaimTypes`'s namespace?